# Confidence interval around difference of regression coefficients

Tags: regression

I am interested in comparing standardized regression coefficients within the same model. A linear hypothesis test (e.g., `car::linearHypothesis` in R) can tell me whether the difference between them is significant, and I can calculate the difference to get a point estimate. However, I am not sure how to get a CI around that.

Currently, I believe that I can use $\beta_\delta$ + 1.96 * $\sqrt{SE1^2+SE2^2}$ in the same way that I would deal with the difference between two means, but I am not sure if that is applicable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula isn't correct, because regression coefficient estimates are typically correlated with each other. It assumes that the variance of the difference of the estimates equals the sum of their individual variances. That's only true for uncorrelated variables. Statistical software can report the variance-covariance matrix for the coefficient estimates. The off-diagonal values of that matrix represent the corresponding covariances between pairs of coefficient estimates. The linear hypothesis tests take the covariances into account.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) shows the more general formula for the variance of a weighted sum or difference of two correlated variables. In you case for a simple difference, it's the sum of the individual variances minus twice their covariance.

$$\operatorname{Var}(X - Y) =\operatorname{Var}(X) +  \operatorname{Var}(Y) -2 \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$$

Taking the square root gives the standard error of the difference. The factor of 1.96 is for 95% confidence limits based on a normal distribution.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @EdM's answer, one option to make that comparison is to use the `multcomp` package, There are details about how the coefficients and standard errors are estimated in chapter 3 of the [book](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio_N/R_Eng/Bretz2011.pdf)

So if we use an example:

```
set.seed(111)
data = iris[sample(nrow(iris),replace=TRUE),]

table(data$Species)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        51         56         43 

md=lm(Petal.Length~Species,data=data)

Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.96250 -0.25792 -0.02549  0.23750  1.15581 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        1.52549    0.05822   26.20   <2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor  2.73701    0.08048   34.01   <2e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica   4.01870    0.08608   46.68   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

library(multcomp)

summary(glht(md,linfct=mcp(Species="Tukey")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
versicolor - setosa == 0     2.73701    0.08048   34.01   <2e-16 ***
virginica - setosa == 0      4.01870    0.08608   46.68   <2e-16 ***
virginica - versicolor == 0  1.28169    0.08431   15.20   <2e-16 ***
```

Note for the confidence interval part, a multiple testing correction is introduced for more than 1 comparisons:

```
confint(glht(md,linfct=mcp(Species="Tukey")))

     Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

    Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
    
    Fit: lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = data)
    
    Quantile = 2.3675
    95% family-wise confidence level
     
    Linear Hypotheses:
                                Estimate lwr    upr   
    versicolor - setosa == 0    2.7370   2.5465 2.9275
    virginica - setosa == 0     4.0187   3.8149 4.2225
    virginica - versicolor == 0 1.2817   1.0821 1.4813
```